# SharePoint in an IFrame

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, iframe

I am trying to embed SharePoint in an Iframe of an html page. I did some research and found out I had to embed:

```
<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat=”server” />
```

into the master page of SharePoint.

I made the above change and SharePoint is now showing up correctly in an iFrame for me and a few other users.

However, some accounts are still getting the security message:

> "This content cannot be displayed in a frame".

I know these accounts can view the page when they go to it directly, as well as when they click **Open this content in a new window**.

Any ideas on what might be going on? I tried the accounts on other machines and still the same issue. My account works fine on multiple machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you publish and approve the master page?
Very often, we edit the master page, test it and are happy with the changes. But we forget to publish/approve it, so users with read-only rights don't see the new version of it...

Comment: This worked! I was having a bug with SP Designer. It already thought the file was checked-in, when in fact it wasn't. I had to check it out and check-it back in for this to work. Thanks!